# MATLAB pass figure handles via Feval C#

Tags: c#, matlab, matlab-figure

Is it possible to pass a figure handle from MATLAB to C# using Feval()? I have a GUI in C# that uses MATLAB.Feval() to plot several figures in separate windows. I'd like for the user to be able to manipulate those figures from C#, but when I return the figure handle (gcf) to C# it is always null.

Comment: A handle is an integer so of course you can return an integer from matlab to c#.

Comment: Matlab data is stored on the execution stack in c# so when you return from a matlab function the data is disposed.  So a figure will not exist when you return back to matlab a 2nd time unless you do something to preserve the figure.